# BigQuery Execute Immediate Identifier issue

Tags: loops, google-bigquery, execute-immediate

I am creating a BQ Stored Procedure to truncate all the tables in a dataset. I have a 2 step process. Step 1 identifies all the matching tables. Step 2 is expected to iterate thru each table and truncate.

I have the following code to achieve this:

```
for record in
 ( select TABLE_NAME 
  from <staging_dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  )
DO
  execute immediate 
  "truncate table @tab" using record.TABLE_NAME as tab;
END FOR;
```

The Error that I am running into is in the *Execute Immediate* piece.

```
Invalid EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql string `truncate table @tab`, Syntax error: Unexpected "@" at [8:3]
```

I tried replacing the @tab with ? placeholder and see a similar error. What am I doing wrong?
Is there another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: if @tab is a variable, then remove @.

Comment: Removing the @ didn`t work. I replaced @tab with @tabl1 and still run into the same problem.

Comment: So yu mean to say u are now using "@tabl1" intead of '@tab'?. If yes then, it wont work. WHat i meant to say is use just 'tab' or 'tabl1'.

Comment: To clarify, I replaced tab with tab1 in both places like here: `"truncate table @tab1" using record.TABLE_NAME as tab1;`

Answer (score 1):

Strange; it seems DML doesn't work with `USING`. Queries work fine.

Try using `CONCAT` to build your dynamic query string:

```
CONCAT("truncate table ", record.TABLE_NAME);
```